# Distinct values in Z3

Tags: z3

I wanted to ask a question about assigning distinct values in Z3.

suppose that I have 6 variables A,B,C,D,E,F. 
Now, I would like to assign distinct values to some of them and some of them will be zero. How many variables will be distinct and how many variables are zero is unknown before-hand. It depends on certain other conditions.

generally for all the variables I shall write

`(assert (distinct A B C D E F))`

However is it possible to write constraint such as `A, B, D` are zero and others are distinct? Again remember that `A,B, D` are just example variables. They can change dynamically depending on the constraints.

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I understand, you have a set *V* of variables *v<sub>1</sub>, ..., v<sub>n</sub>*, where each variable *v<sub>i</sub>* is either zero or different from all other variables *v<sub>j</sub>, j ≠ i*.

As an example, let `V = {a, b, c, d}`.

```
(declare-const a Int)
(declare-const b Int)
(declare-const c Int)
(declare-const d Int)
```

You could encode your constraints as

```
(assert (or (= a 0) (not (or (= a b) (= a c) (= a d)))))
(assert (or (= b 0) (not (or (= b a) (= b c) (= b d)))))
(assert (or (= c 0) (not (or (= c a) (= c b) (= c d)))))
(assert (or (= d 0) (not (or (= d a) (= d b) (= d c)))))
```

Adding two constraints and querying Z3 for a model

```
(assert (= a 0))
(assert (not (= b 0)))

(check-sat)
(get-model)
```

then yields

```
sat
(model 
  (define-fun b () Int
    (- 2))
  (define-fun c () Int
    (- 1))
  (define-fun d () Int
    0)
  (define-fun a () Int
    0)
)
```

Since generating the "zero or distinct" constraints is a tedious task you'd probably want to work with a Z3 front-end such as PyZ3 or Scala^Z3.

Comment: this is what I do right now. but I was wondering if there is a way to avoid it. Thank You for your reply !

Comment: Not that I know of. But if, then I am confident that one of the Z3 developers will let you know pretty soon :-) I think that having a `distinct` function would be nice in general, especially if the set of variables is not known upfront. It probably wouldn't help you much, since you have the relaxed constraint that multiple variables can be zero.

Comment: yeah, I think it would be best if there was a function where we can say, that the values are either distinct or a constant like zero for example.

Comment: Oh, I just noticed that Z3 actually has a `distinct` keyword. I wasn't aware of that. Anyway, I guess that your use-case is too specific to warrant a built-in function. Especially, since PyZ3 etc are available.

Comment: yes, earlier I used `distinct` keyword to do the similar encoding. So I was searching for its variant. :)